# 53:6: warning: conflicting types for function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct students{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    int height;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct students manoj;

    strcpy(manoj.name, "manojkumar");
    manoj.age = 15;

    displaymanoj(&manoj); //print testing \n , name , age 

    return 0;
}

void displaymanoj(struct students *ptr) {
    printf("Testing...............DEBUG\n");
    printf("%s\t%d\n", ptr->name,ptr->age);
    printf("END OF TEST: SUCESS -manoj-");
}
```

I am learning C and it's working where is use pointer to point to structure variable. I am getting the correct output when I run the program. Just that my Geany IDE giving out some message which I would like to know why.

My Compiler Message as below :

Answer (score 2):

You must *declare* the functions before calling them.

So your program should look something like

```
// Includes
// Structure

// Function prototype declaration
// This was what you were missing before
void displaymanoj(struct students *ptr);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
}

void displaymanoj(struct students *ptr) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the definition of `displaymanoj()` isn't seen when you call it from `main()`, compiler implicitly declares one with return type `int`
which conflicts with the actual one. Note that the *implicit declaration* has been removed since the C99 standard and is no longer valid.

To fix it:

1) Either move the function `displaymanoj()` above main()'s definition or
2) Do a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of `displaymanoj()`.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it by declaring above main . What is actually mean by  'implcit declaration'

Comment: I am 16 and new to c programming

Comment: When you compiler sees a function for the first time, and if it hasn't seen a declaration of that function yet, then the compiler implicitly declares one with `int` as return type. This is called implicit function declaration as the compiler does it for you. This is an old rule that existed before C99. In C99, this rule was removed and all functions are now required to have the declarations (definitions also provide declarations -- that's how moving the function above main() works).